# Loading a PHP file in Chrome displays PHP codes

Tags: php, apache, fedora

**The Problem:**
Exactly as it says. My phpinfo.php file contains the following:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The file itself is located in `/var/www/html/info.php`.

**What I did (prior to the problem):**
I erased all installations of PHP, oci8, and what not. I'm not sure if I did a good job - basically, I typed in `yum history` and then undid every install relating to PHP.

This was so I could have a clean system (supposedly), before trying all the PHP stuff again, without resorting to a reformat - I had Oracle 11g and apache already setup there.

Take note, before this complete wipeout, said file up there was working fine.

To install PHP with oci8, I followed a guide [here](http://antoine.hordez.fr/2012/09/30/howto-install-oracle-oci8-on-rhel-centos-fedora/), with some differences, but I'll list it down, just the same.

- yum install php-pear
- yum install php-devel
- pear download pecl/oci8
- tar xvzf oci8-2.0.6.tgz
- cd oci8-2.0.6
- phpize
- ./configure --with-oci8=$ORACLE_HOME
- make
- make install
- setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1

Afterwards, I added the following at the very end of `/etc/php.ini` file:
[OCI8]
extension=oci8.so

Then, I restarted apache via `service httpd restart`.

And then, I encountered the problem.

**The System:**

- Fedora 19 x86_64
- Oracle 11g
- Apache 2.4.6

**What I tried:**
I thought at first it was Konqueror's problem. Fiddling with the View settings sometimes fixed it - most of the time, it did nothing.

So I installed Google Chrome, which displayed the same thing.

At this point I went, what the heck, I just installed php via `yum install php`. Maybe `php-pear` or `php-devel` on its own is not enough to run a php file.

No dice. All I wanted was to start over and install PHP with oci8 from scratch.

It appears PHP itself has a problem, and I'm stuck. A bit of research online says something about the tags, that php can't run `<?.... ?>`, as opposed to `<?php ..... ?>`, but as you can see with my phpinfo example, it didn't help much.

**Other Information:**
I get this from PHP's error log. I'm not sure if it means anything, as I recall seeing something like this back before I nuked my system, but perhaps they can be of some use.

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated
>   directory index forbidden by Options directive
>
> AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

They don't seem to appear in the error log at any predictable frequency - loading up any PHP file or restarting apache are the only two things I've done.

Comment: what do you get if you run `php -i` from command line (assuming CLI is installed and in path)?

Comment: ensure that your file extension is .php

Comment: @Anthony, I get a pretty long list of sessions, variables, environments, etc.

Comment: @alok.kumar, yes, the file extension is php. The file name is `info.php`

Answer (score 4):

It's not the browser. Probably, you don't have php module activated in your Apache. Look at your httpd.conf, and put the following lines there:

```
# Load the PHP module:
LoadModule php5_module lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so

# Tell Apache to feed all *.php files through PHP.  If you'd like to
# parse PHP embedded in files with different extensions, comment out
# these lines and see the example below.
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I added this to the very end of the httpd.conf file. It didn't work, even after I restarted the apache.

Comment: @zack_falcon This code is copied from my httpd.conf. Change php5_module to your dir if necessary. On my machine, they are located in `/usr/lib/httpd/modules`

Comment: @zack_falcon I am absolutely sure, that if you see text of php file, instead of result of it's execution, the module is not working, and the error is lurking here.

Comment: I found it in `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so/`, and changed the line to that. When that didn't work, I changed it to `lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so/`. Unfortunately, it didn't work either.

Comment: @zack_falcon Why do you have a slash at the end? Is the path to file: /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so/libphp5.so?

Comment: My mistake, and I couldn't edit it anymore. The path is indeed `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`, and that is what is written in the httpd.conf file, to no effect.

Comment: @zack_falcon can you execute the same file from console php?

Comment: If you mean `php /var/www/html/info.php`, then yes, it could be executed.

Comment: @zack_falcon Unfortunately, I am out of ideas. For some reason your php file is not processed by php module. It's a very easy thing: the libphp5.so file must be present in the modules directory, included into httpd.conf and handler set for php files. Try to investigate yourself.

Comment: Thanks for trying, just the same. Perhaps that tutorial I followed wasn't good, or I broke something during my uninstalls. If all else fails, I'll reformat and start over.